# How to disable "Turn Off Airplane Mode or Use Wi-Fi to Access Data" message for my html5 offline app?

Tags: iphone, html, offline

on iOS devices, is there a way to programmatically disable the browser message "Turn Off Airplane Mode or Use Wi-Fi to Access Data" when my app is intentionnaly on Airplane Mode and works already properly offline?

Many thanks!

Comment: how is this being done? phonegap? html5 offline storage?

Comment: yes it uses sencha-touch frwk, without phonegap, pure html5 directly download from web to the device

Comment: so jQuery Mobile and Sencha SDK and html5 offline storage ... you need to scan the Sencha docs to see what kind of control over the device you may access (stickys, broadcasts, phone call recognition, etc.). I could tell you what to do with the phonegap API, but not sure if it is even possible with sencha and html5 offline.

Comment: Hi, have you found the answer?